# How to detect the collision of circles or balls in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I want to make a script in pygame where two balls fly towards each other and when they collide they should bounce off from each other but I don't know how to do this so can you help me?

Comment: Please post the code you currently have

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pygame circle collision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642234/pygame-circle-collision)

Comment: [duplicate] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642234/pygame-circle-collision

Comment: to compute the redirection after collision (bounce effect) you should check some tutorials that will explain visually how this works. Just found out this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlwtgvZCz0k which seems to be short and clear. It's not python but the concepts will be the same

Comment: also, you might want to check this community which is more about game dev: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To detect if 2 circles (respectively balls) are colliding, you've to test, if the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between the circles center points is less than the sum of the radii. I recommend to use [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) / [`distance_to()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to) for the computation.
In the following the 1 circle is defined by the center point *(x1, y1)* and the radius *r1*. The 2nd circle is defined by *(x2, y2)* and *r2*:

```py
v1 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1, y1)
v2 = pygame.math.Vector2(x2, y2)
if v1.distance_to(v2) < r1 + r2:
    print("hit")
```

If you have to test many collisions between circles you should compare the square of the distances to avoid the time consuming square root calculation necessary to calculate Euclidean distance. With [`distance_squared_to()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.distance_squared_to) there is also a function for this:

```py
v1 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1, y1)
v2 = pygame.math.Vector2(x2, y2)
if v1.distance_squared_to(v2) < (r1 + r2)**2:
    print("hit")
```

If you want to make the circles bounce, you have to reflect the motion vector of the circle at the normal vector of the intersection like a billiard ball. Use  [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) / [`reflect_ip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.reflect_ip) or [`reflect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.reflect) to compute the new direction of the circle.
The movements of the circles are given by *(mx1, my1)* and  *(mx2, my2)*:

```py
nv = v2 - v1
m1 = pygame.math.Vector2(mx1, my1).reflect(nv)
m2 = pygame.math.Vector2(mx2, my2).reflect(nv)
mx1, my1 = m1.x, m1.y
mx2, my2 = m2.x, m2.y
```

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-CirclesBounceOff](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-CirclesBounceOff#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

width, height = 400, 400
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x1, y1, r1, mx1, my1 = 200, 200, 50, 2, 0.5
x2, y2, r2, mx2, my2 = 300, 200, 50, -1, -1.5

def move(c, v, r, m):
    c += v
    if c < r: c, v = r, -v
    if c > m-r: c, v = m-r, -v   
    return c, v

hit_count = 0
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    x1, mx1 = move(x1, mx1, r1, width)
    y1, my1 = move(y1, my1, r1, height)
    x2, mx2 = move(x2, mx2, r2, width)
    y2, my2 = move(y2, my2, r2, height)

    v1 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1, y1)
    v2 = pygame.math.Vector2(x2, y2)
    if v1.distance_to(v2) < r1 + r2 - 2:
        hit_count += 1
        print("hit:", hit_count)

        nv = v2 - v1
        m1 = pygame.math.Vector2(mx1, my1).reflect(nv)
        m2 = pygame.math.Vector2(mx2, my2).reflect(nv)
        mx1, my1 = m1.x, m1.y
        mx2, my2 = m2.x, m2.y

    window.fill((127, 127, 127))
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 0, 0), (round(x1), round(y1)), r1, 4)
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (0, 0, 255), (round(x2), round(y2)), r2, 4)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score -1):

Its pretty easy you just check if the x coordinate is in the same spot as the other x coordinate. For example if you had one of the x coordinated called x, and another one called i(there are 2 x coordinates for both of the balls) then you could just say if oh and before I say anything esle this example is fi your pygame window is a 500,500. You could say if x == 250: x -= 15. And the other way around for i. If i == 250: i += 15. Ther you go!. Obviously there are a few changes you have to do, but this is the basic code, and I think you would understand this