# pygame Get the balls to bounce off each other

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to get the balls to bounce off each other. I tried to do it using the `reflect()` method, but it doesn't work for some reason.
To detect the balls, I used `groupcollide`, since I couldn't think of a better way, maybe this is wrong?

```
import pygame
import random

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, startpos, velocity, startdir):
        super().__init__()
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(startpos)
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.dir = pygame.math.Vector2(startdir).normalize()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("small_ball.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)))

    def reflect(self, NV):
        self.dir = self.dir.reflect(pygame.math.Vector2(NV))

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.dir * 10
        self.rect.center = round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)

        if self.rect.left <= 0:
            self.reflect((1, 0))
        if self.rect.right >= 700:
            self.reflect((-1, 0))
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.reflect((0, 1))
        if self.rect.bottom >= 700:
            self.reflect((0, -1))

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption('noname')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

all_balls = pygame.sprite.Group()

start, velocity, direction = (200, 200), 10, (random.random(), random.random())
ball_1 = Ball(start, velocity, direction)

start, velocity, direction = (200, 200), 10, (random.random(), random.random())
ball_2 = Ball(start, velocity, direction)

all_balls.add(ball_1, ball_2)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    all_balls.update()

    hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(all_balls, all_balls, False, False)
    for _, hit_sprites in hits.items():
        if len(hit_sprites) > 1:
            sprite_1 = hit_sprites[0]
            sprite_2 = hit_sprites[1]
            sprite_1.reflect((0, 1)) # not working
            print("hit!")

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 700, 700), 1)
    all_balls.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image: small_ball.png]

Comment: You have to define a circle, that represents the ball. Then you can use the algorithm from [Pygame how to let balls collide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63145493/pygame-how-to-let-balls-collide) to bounce the balls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a circle by the ball Sprites and use the algorithm from the answer to [Pygame how to let balls collide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63145493/pygame-how-to-let-balls-collide) for a function, that can compute reflection of bouncing balls:

```py
def reflectBalls(ball_1, ball_2):
    v1 = pygame.math.Vector2(ball_1.rect.center)
    v2 = pygame.math.Vector2(ball_2.rect.center)
    r1 = ball_1.rect.width // 2
    r2 = ball_2.rect.width // 2
    if v1.distance_to(v2) < r1 + r2 - 2:
        nv = v2 - v1
        if nv.length() > 0:
            ball_1.dir = ball_1.dir.reflect(nv)
            ball_2.dir = ball_2.dir.reflect(nv)
```

Ensure that the balls have different initial positions:

```py
start, velocity, direction = (200, 200), 10, (random.random(), random.random())
ball_1 = Ball(start, velocity, direction)

start, velocity, direction = (300, 300), 10, (random.random(), random.random())
ball_2 = Ball(start, velocity, direction)
```

Alternatively you can avoid that the balls are sticking together by improving the *bounce* algorithm. Only bounce the balls, if the next positions of the balls are closer then the current positions:

```py
def reflectBalls(ball_1, ball_2):
    v1 = pygame.math.Vector2(ball_1.rect.center)
    v2 = pygame.math.Vector2(ball_2.rect.center)
    r1 = ball_1.rect.width // 2
    r2 = ball_2.rect.width // 2
    d = v1.distance_to(v2)
    if d < r1 + r2 - 2:
        dnext = (v1 + ball_1.dir).distance_to(v2 + ball_2.dir)
        nv = v2 - v1
        if dnext < d and nv.length() > 0:
            ball_1.dir = ball_1.dir.reflect(nv)
            ball_2.dir = ball_2.dir.reflect(nv)
```

Test if each ball collides with any other ball:

```py
ball_list = all_balls.sprites()
for i, b1 in enumerate(ball_list):
    for b2 in ball_list[i+1:]:
        reflectBalls(b1, b2)
```

---

Complete example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-BallsBounceOff](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-BallsBounceOff#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame
import random

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, startpos, velocity, startdir):
        super().__init__()
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(startpos)
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.dir = pygame.math.Vector2(startdir).normalize()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("small_ball.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)))

    def reflect(self, NV):
        self.dir = self.dir.reflect(pygame.math.Vector2(NV))

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.dir * 10
        self.rect.center = round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)

        if self.rect.left <= 0:
            self.reflect((1, 0))
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.right >= 700:
            self.reflect((-1, 0))
            self.rect.right = 700
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.reflect((0, 1))
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom >= 700:
            self.reflect((0, -1))
            self.rect.bottom = 700

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption('noname')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

all_balls = pygame.sprite.Group()

start, velocity, direction = (200, 200), 10, (random.random(), random.random())
ball_1 = Ball(start, velocity, direction)

start, velocity, direction = (300, 300), 10, (random.random(), random.random())
ball_2 = Ball(start, velocity, direction)

all_balls.add(ball_1, ball_2)

def reflectBalls(ball_1, ball_2):
    v1 = pygame.math.Vector2(ball_1.rect.center)
    v2 = pygame.math.Vector2(ball_2.rect.center)
    r1 = ball_1.rect.width // 2
    r2 = ball_2.rect.width // 2
    d = v1.distance_to(v2)
    if d < r1 + r2 - 2:
        dnext = (v1 + ball_1.dir).distance_to(v2 + ball_2.dir)
        nv = v2 - v1
        if dnext < d and nv.length() > 0:
            ball_1.reflect(nv)
            ball_2.reflect(nv)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    all_balls.update()

    ball_list = all_balls.sprites()
    for i, b1 in enumerate(ball_list):
        for b2 in ball_list[i+1:]:
            reflectBalls(b1, b2)

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 700, 700), 1)
    all_balls.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, at first glance I liked the solution, but I noticed that from time to time the balls fly off incorrectly, what could be the problem? This is especially noticeable with 3 balls

Comment: @CoffeeinTime That is caused by the fact that `velocity` is grater than 1. This causes that the collision is not exactly detected when the balls are touching. When the collision is detected, the balls are already overlapping. It is up to you to improve the algorithm.